# Считывание из файлов Eclipse C++ (ubuntu)

Tags: eclipse, c++, ubuntu

В общем создаю текстовый файл в gedit пихаю его в проект, и компилирую(предварительно нажав на проекте Build)
Вместо того что находится в файлах считываются все нули.
Помогите разобраться вот исходник:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int sqr(int Arg_X,int Arg_Y){

  int Arg_X2=Arg_X*Arg_Y;

  return(Arg_X2);
}

int main() {

  int a;

  ifstream f("file.txt");

  for(int i=1;i<4;i++){

      f >> a;

      cout <<a<<endl;
  }

}
```

Я не знаю какое расширение стоит по умолчанию в gedit, и может поможет указание прямого пути к файлу(как это реализовать не знаю).

Comment: "какое расширение стоит по умолчанию в gedit", - что Вы имеете ввиду?

Comment: Ну я указыаю file.txt, на Убунту 2 день (текстовик создал с помощью gedit)
Расширение созданного файла я не нашел где посмотреть.

Comment: ты из потока все пихаешь в переменную int? считывание файла нужно делать до EOF ну или до любого ругого условия. ifstream  это поток

Comment: @FlagShtok если судить по Вашим вопросам, то Вам нужно сначала ознакомиться с Linux и C++.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
int main () {
 std::ifstream f("test.txt", std::ifstream::in);
  while (f != 0) {
   std::cout << (char) f.get();
   }
  std::cout << "\ndone" << std::endl;
  f.close();
 return 0;
 }
```